# Using jQuery UI Tabs feature, getting multiple rows for buttons but should only have one row

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

using jQuery UI tabs and would expect a single row of tabs to show based on number of buttons, but have multiple rows showing.  This is being used with Bootstrap gridding and perhaps that is causing the issue.

[image: Example of multiple tab rows when only one should be needed]

Using:

- jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2020-11-09
- Bootstrap v4.5.0

HTML definition:

```
<div id="informationSourceTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#customerNameRefineryTab">Customer Name Refinery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#customerSSOT_APISourceTag">Customer Registry</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="customerNameRefineryTab">

        ....

    </div>
    <div id="customerSSOT_APISourceTag">

        ....

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#informationSourceTabs").tabs();
```

Rather straightforward stuff.  Any ideas would be really helpful.

Comment: May I ask why you're using jQueryUI tabs (very old, unsupported for 5 years) when you have Bootstrap tabs available?

Comment: Also, your screenshot doesn't seem to show multiple rows. Where's the problem?

Comment: Not a bad question actually - not sure why I didn't see Bootstrap tab functionality when I looked the other day.  Can you point me to where in its documentation it is specified?  Bootstrap doc is sometimes a bit less than direct.  Would certainly consider a shift away from jQuery for this

Comment: @isherwood - see those black stripes - those are jQuery UI tab "rows"

Comment: The search box is your friend. :) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#tabs

Comment: I don't see black stripes. I see two tabs in a black box.

Comment: Look at that!  Yes, this dude needs friends!  Thanks a bunch.  Not that I want to end the quest for knowledge, but I am gonna go ahead and move in that direction for everyone's sanity.  Thank you for the callout!